# binding combobox images - how to select saved item in combobox images

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a Problem with the ComboBox at wpf and xaml. The ItemsSource of my combobox is a list of (CollarTypesImage). 
the binding is work fine but the problem when editing data, i can't select the item of my ComboBox.. maybe its selected but the image is not view...

but when click ComboBox, i can see all itams:

http://www.ahmadabouhamdh.com/tmp_global/1.png

i used RelativeSource , nothing changed, ComboBox not selection the my saved item:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TailorManager.Views.OrderDetailItem"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
   xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TailorManager.ViewModels" 
  xmlns:Converter="clr-namespace:TailorManager.Converters"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="730" d:DesignWidth="556" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <!--<vm:OrderDetailItemViewModel x:Key="OrderDetailItemViewModel1" />-->
    <Converter:ImageConverter x:Key="ImgConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid >
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
        <ItemsControl>
            <StackPanel> 
                <GroupBox Header="تفاصيل الياقة" Margin="5,5,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="170">
                    <Grid>
                       <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path= DataContext.ImagesCollarTypes,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl,AncestorLevel=1}}" 
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=OrderDetailItem.CollarTypesImage,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                                  SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=OrderDetailItem.CollarTypesImage}"
                                  Margin="393,106,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="132" Height="38">
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="{Binding Path= CollarImage,Converter={StaticResource ImgConverter} }" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate >
                        </ComboBox>

                    </Grid>
                </GroupBox> 
                <Grid/>
            </StackPanel>

        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

i added

```
 SelectedItem="{Binding Path=OrderDetailItem.CollarTypesImage}"
```

and nothing changed.

i use this Control inside window has a different DataContext type,i set the value of  (DataContext OrderDetailItem) from constructor of this control.

image below explain the binding is working fine:

this image when click edit to show my saved image from DB, my item not selected:

http://www.ahmadabouhamdh.com/tmp_global/2.png

### here all the code:

```
    public List<CollarTypesImage> ImagesCollarTypes
    {
        get
        {
            //ImagesCollarTypes[0].CollarImage
            if (_imagesCollarTypes.Count == 0)
            {
                TailorManagerDBEntities db = new TailorManagerDBEntities();
                _imagesCollarTypes = db.CollarTypesImages.ToList();
            }
            return _imagesCollarTypes;
        }
        set
        {
            _imagesCollarTypes = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => ImagesCollarTypes);
        }
    }
```

---

```
public partial class CollarTypesImage
{
    public CollarTypesImage()
    {
        this.OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetail>();
    }

    public System.Guid CollarTypeId { get; set; }
    public byte[] CollarImage { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

---

here the xaml code from window i used my control:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TailorManager.ViewModels"
    xmlns:util="clr-namespace:TailorManagerLib.Business;assembly=TailorManagerLib"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TailorManager.Views"
x:Class="TailorManager.Views.AddOrder"
    Title="AddCustomer" Height="665" Width="974" MinWidth="600" MinHeight="666" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" >
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:ManageOrderDetilsViewModel x:Key="ManageOrderDetilsViewModel1" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ManageOrderDetilsViewModel1}" x:Name="GridDataContaner">
    <Grid.Background>
       ...
    </Grid.Background>

    <GroupBox Header="تفاصيل الطلب" Margin="10,160,10,0" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Name="GridOrderDetails">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Name="ColumnDefinitionListDetails" Width="183*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Name="ColumnDefinitionDetails" Width="0*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,40" >
               ...
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3" Margin="4" >
                    <Grid>
                       <local:OrderDetailItem x:Name="OrderDetailItemControl" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

            </Grid>
            ...
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

---

how i set the DataContext of the Control, this inside the command in VM of my window:

```
OrderDetailItemViewModel OrdDetailItem = new OrderDetailItemViewModel(Ord.OrderDetailsId);
OrderDetailItemControl.DataContext = OrdDetailItem;
```

Please how to fix it??

---

> > > UPDATE

when i change the relative source as below:

```
<ComboBox Name="CmbBxImgCollarTyp" ItemsSource="{Binding Path= DataContext.ImagesCollarTypes, RelativeSource={
RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:OrderDetailItemViewModel}}" 
SelectedValue="{Binding Path=OrderDetailItem.CollarTypesImage, Mode=TwoWay,
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path= OrderDetailItem.CollarTypesImage}" Margin="393,106,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="132" Height="38">
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="{Binding Path=CollarImage,
            Converter={StaticResource ImgConverter}}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
```

the binding never work at all modes!, i change it to this way cause the datacontext of this control is an object of the viewmodel "OrderDetailItemViewModel" 
What should be fix؟؟

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after check the *Output*  window, i notes this error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with 
reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='Projectname.ViewModels.ViewModel', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=LookupItems; DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
```

then i change the RelativeSource from AncestorType from my ViewModel to UserControl, just like this:
 `RelativeSource={ AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1}}"`

and now everything working fine,

Thanks for members make an effort

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your `RelativeSource Binding Path`. You have used the type of `UserControl`, but the `UserControl` class does *not* have a property named `ImagesCollarTypes`... instead, you should use *your* `UserControl` where you defined the property... I'm assuming that class was named `OrderDetailItem`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path= DataContext.ImagesCollarTypes, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourViewsPrefix:OrderDetailItem}}}" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CollarTypesImage, Mode=TwoWay,
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=
    CollarTypesImage}" Margin="393,106,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="132" Height="38">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="{Binding Path=CollarImage,
                Converter={StaticResource ImgConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

You should have received an error in the Output Window in Visual Studio saying something like *Error: property '`ImagesCollarTypes`' not found on object '`UserControl`'* or something similar.

> Disclaimer: I didn't go through all of your code because you simply have too much there, so even after you fix this error, your code may still have other errors and not work as expected.

---

UPDATE >>>

For this `Binding` to work, the following assumptions were made:

1. The `UserControl.DataContext` must have a valid instance of an object set.
2. The object set as the `UserControl.DataContext` must have a public property named `ImagesCollarTypes`.
3. The `ImagesCollarTypes` property must be of a type that contains a public property named `CollarTypesImage`.

Comment: hi Sheridan, Thank you very much for replay..
actually am not received any error ... i set your updates and no changes!

I still have the same problem

Comment: *actually am not received any error*... how can that be? You had a clear `Binding` error. Have you ever seen any errors in your Output Window? Perhaps they're switched off in your options. Either way, I updated the code... take another look.

Comment: really, no errors.. kindly check the iamges..
http://www.ahmadabouhamdh.com/tmp_global/3.png
http://www.ahmadabouhamdh.com/tmp_global/4.png

Comment: Why show me your UI to prove you have no errors in the *Output Window in Visual Studio*? They're not shown in the UI, they're shown in the *Output Window in Visual Studio*.

Comment: Sheridan, The DataContext of UserControl "OrderDetailItem" is a new object from the viewmodel "OrderDetailItemViewModel", and this constructor build like this:


        public OrderDetailItemViewModel(Guid OrderDetailID)
        {
            if (OrderDetailID != Guid.Empty)
            {
                TailorManagerDBEntities db = new TailorManagerDBEntities();
                OrderDetailItem = db.OrderDetails.SingleOrDefault(q     => q.OrderDetailsId == OrderDetailID);

            }
        } 

this "OrderDetailID" Property is public property

Comment: Please don't add code into comments as it is very difficult to see clearly. If you have to add code, you should add it into your question in an edit. Having said that, I'm really not sure why you've shown your constructor code - it seems pretty irrelevant to me. That just means that your `OrderDetails` database table has a property named `OrderDetailID` in it. Either way... what error(s) are you getting *in the Output Window in Visual Studio*?

Comment: this is the Error Output:
    
 System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'TailorManagerLib' property not found on 'object' ''CollarTypesImage' (HashCode=8694740)'. BindingExpression:Path=TailorManagerLib.DB.CollarTypesImage; DataItem='CollarTypesImage' (HashCode=8694740); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='CmbBxImgCollarTyp'); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

Comment: You've not even shown the relevant code. Your error complains about a property named `TailorManagerLib`, but your code doesn't show where you tried to data bind using it. (I am well aware that it is your Namespace, but your error says that you've used it somewhere in your XAML). You need to do some work yourself now... I'm tired of continually returning here to waste further time. If you want further help, you'd better provide *all of the relevant information (and only the relevant information) in your question*. You have not done this so far.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts and your time, i will try to understand this problem

Comment: To be clear, I'm *not* saying that I won't help you further... I just need you to provide me with *all* of the relevant information for me to be able to fix your problem. And preferably in one go, not a little bit here and a little bit there.